# Left join MYSQL returns false

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I am trying to do a MYSQL LEFT JOIN query, however I'm getting an error: 
"Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in". Because the query which is returned is false.

The code is:

```
$query = "
SELECT a.page
     , SUM(b.views) views
     , ROUND(SUM(b.costs)/1.38,2) costs
     , ROUND(SUM(a.amount),2) REV
     , ROUND(SUM(a.amount) - SUM(b.costs)/1.38,2) PNL  
  FROM revenues a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN costs b 
    ON a.page = b.page
 WHERE a.date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
   AND a.country = '$country' 
   AND b.date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
 GROUP 
    BY a.page";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if ($result != false) {
  $foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($foundnum == 0) {
    echo 'No results found.';
  }
} else {
    echo 'returned false';
}

printQuery($result);
```

printQuery is a function of me which creates a html table.

If I do two seperate queries on the tables I get correct tables back. My seperate queries are:

```
$query = "SELECT page, round(sum(amount),2) as REV FROM revenues WHERE date between '$start_date' AND '$end_date' AND country = '$country' GROUP BY page" ;

$query2 = "SELECT page, sum(views) as views, round(sum(costs)/1.38,2) as costs FROM costs WHERE date between '$start_date' AND '$end_date' GROUP BY page";
```

Can someone please point to me where the mistake is.

Table revenues consists of the columns:
date: date
amount: float (NULL if no revenue was made)
country: varchar

Table costs cosists of the columns:
date: date
costs: float (always >= 0)
views: int

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a vardump() of your query : vardump($query);

Comment: Have you tried to do echo mysqli_error(); to see if there might be an error in your sql-query that makes mysqli_query() return false?

Comment: Use "$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));"

Comment: The predicates on `b` in the `WHERE` clause negate the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operation, making it equivalent to an INNER JOIN. To make it an outer join, the predicates that require columns from `b` to be non-null can be relocated to the ON clause. That doesn't explain the error though. For debugging, add `echo $query;` after the string is set, and `echo mysqli_error();` after `echo false;`. I don't see a syntax problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is usless:

```
else {
    echo 'returned false';
}
```

Replace it with something like:

```
else {
    echo "Query failed.\nMySQLi error: " . mysqli_error();
}
```

You get points for at least checking your return values, but you need to make your code fail *descriptively* at least for dev purposes.